# How to translate "hot dog" in France French?

Tags: traduction, québec, alimentation, france

In Canadian French, people use the term « chien-chaud » , literal translation of "hot dog". Apparently this is only used in Quebec, so I'm wondering how people say it in France or other French-speaking parts of the world. Unfortunately Google Translate just seems to hyphenate the word when I type in "hot dog".

I'm referring to the food, not the animal:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Non. Les québécois pour une large part ont rejeté catégoriquement *chien chaud*. Si quelqu'un employait ce terme, il se ferait rire au nez. *Hot dog* est l'emprunt employé universellement, ainsi que l'indiquera n'importe quel dictionnaire courant.

Comment: I'm not sure which region of Quebec that applies to but here in the Gatineau/Ottawa area, *chien chaud* is pretty common. Good to know though.

Comment: Never heard anybody in Quebec ever say "Chien-chaud" seriously. Edit: I've lived North shore and South Shore of Montreal as well as Montreal itself. I know people from Quebec, Saguenay and Abitibi and all of them would find it very odd in a conversation to use "chien chaud".

Comment: Maybe it's used in a humoristic way but I've never seen chien-chaud neither. I live in the Laurentides.

Comment: Je suis français et utilise généralement "chien chaud". Tout le monde comprend, et même si c'est humoristique je peux vous assurer que jamais personne ne m'a ri au nez !

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur and Circeus: I apologize for this late and slightly off-topic intrusion, mais nous avions deux ami(e)s Bleuet/Bleuette au Saguenay qui disaient plutot "les vapeurs" et parfois "les steamés" pour "hot dogs," et je me (et vous, SVP) demande si cet usage ne s'agissait qu'a leur usage personnel ou est-il un usage connu au Saguenay (et/ou ailleurs)? (Et (last intrusion, I promise) s'il est connu, est-ce qu'il marche uniquement pour les hot dogs cuisent (cuits?) a la vapeur ou pour n'importe qu'elle facon d'en cuire?) Merci beaucoup!!

Comment: @PapaPoule J'ai rarement entendu "vapeur" utilisé pour un hotdog vapeur, mais "steamé" oui (emprunt et francisation de "steamed hotdogs"). Similairement, à Montréal on peut entendre parler de "steamies" qui fait un peu plus anglo. Aussi oui, ça réfère seulement aux hot-dogs cuits à la vapeur.

Answer (score 8):

In France, it is called *hot-dog*.

But this kind of street food is far less common than *jambon-beurre* or *kebab*.

Comment: en suisse aussi c'est hot-dog ou hotdog et on dit /ɔtdɔg/